# Material UI text orientation top to bottom

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to create an Accordion that opens left-to-right. The Accordion title should thus have a text body that goes top-to-bottom, similar to what can be seen [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-orientation).

This code does not work:

```
 <Typography sx={{textOrientation: 'upright', writingMode: 'vertical'}}>
     Vertical Text
 </Typography>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vertical` value for `writingMode` is not correct. You should use either `vertical-lr` or `vertical-rl`. Also `upright` value for `textOrientation` makes the direction of the sentences vertical (but it does not rotate the letters). Thus for having letters rotated **90° clockwise**, `sideways` value is needed.

```
<Typography sx={{textOrientation: 'sideways', writingMode: 'vertical-lr'}}>
     Vertical Text
</Typography>
```

Comment: can you please elaborate the difference between vertical-rl and vertical-lr? I see the same output with both.

Comment: **vertical-rl**: For `ltr` scripts, content flows vertically from top to bottom, and the next vertical line is positioned to the left of the previous line.
**vertical-lr**: For `ltr` scripts, content flows vertically from top to bottom, and the next vertical line is positioned to the right of the previous line.
You can check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode) out.